# File format for Windows Device Driver

Tags: windows, driver

What extensions could correspond to Windows Device Driver source files? 
Is *.inf, *cat or *.sys it?

I am trying to search for the source code of a driver in a heap of legacy code, I see files with above mentioned extensions.

Comment: Most drivers are written in C, so it is likely that the source code files will have a .c or .cpp extension.

Answer (score 2):

If it is legacy driver and built using command prompt (not newer visual studio), then you better of looking for file named `SOURCES`. It is similar to makefiles and will list driver file name (`somedriver.sys`) as well as list of source files -`.c`- for that driver.

Answer (score 0):

*.sys is the actual driver. inf and cat are for installation parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your device driver source code files will most likely have `.c` and `.h` extensions, they will be written in the C programming language and when compiled will form the executable driver (with the `.sys` extension).

- The `.inf` files are like a script used by Windows to install the device driver into the operating system, they identify the executable file name (your `.sys` files) and how the driver is installed etc.
- The `.cat` files are used to store certificates and the driver signing signatures of the compiled driver, they are used by Windows during installation of the driver to make sure there's nothing malicious going on.

The `.inf` `.cat` and `.sys` files form the Windows driver package needed by the end user, they don't contain the actual source code of the executable driver.

Comment: Thanks @SeF for reviewing my terrible post! It's much clearer now :)